# What is this IC marked 4PC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet, surface-mount

I can't find anything about this SMD IC marked 4PC.

[image]

Comment: Some context would help. What sort of circuit is it in? What components is it connected to? Which pins look like they're connected to power supply rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a UM1431S5-30, a 3V regulator
[image]

Datasheet: http://www.union-ic.com/Upload/Datasheet/Datasheet_UM1431,UM1441_Rev01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

My investigation. Check details in datasheet, mark code section.

- [LN1134](http://www.natlinear.com/uploadfiles/2014/LN/LN1134_E.pdf)
- [XC6105](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6116/XC6101-XC6102-XC6103-XC6104-XC6105-XC6111-XC6112-XC6113-XC6114-XC6115-XC6116-XC6117.pdf)
- [XC6204](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6204/XC6204-XC6205.pdf)